# 3 Camera Capture with videoInput or anything else

Tags: c++, opencv, directshow, video-capture, ms-media-foundation

I am working on project to produce High Dynamic Range Video in real time. The goal is to do it with 3 off the shelf webcams (Microsoft LiveCam Studio). I started off trying to use OpenCV, but I was having difficulties getting it to open the cameras. So I jumped straight to `videoInput`. I can get any two of the cameras to work with each other. And I can get any two webcams to work with the built in webcam on my laptop. But if I try to run all three webcams together, I get

> ERROR: Could not start graph'

After spending several hours investigating `videoInput.cpp` I can not figure out why it would have no problem with two cameras of the same type, but fail when I add the third.

I thought I was almost done with my project when I reached this unexpected wall.

Do you have any thoughts on this?

Windows 7(64)

Visual Studio 2011

I need to get a frame from all 3 cameras in a synced manner. I am open to any suggestions on how to get this done. Is there any other framework out there that will let me avoid DirectShow or MediaFoundation? Does anyone have code that I can look at that will open multiple cameras and pull frames out of the streams?

Comment: Can you try plugging the cameras into ports from different USB hubs?

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that the cameras only connect through directshow (at least on windows), I don't know of any low level API supplied by Microsoft to talk to the cameras directly.

Are you able to run 3 cameras simultaneously using the regular webcam viewer?

It may be a limitation in directshow or the bandwidth of the USB - try connecting them into different ports.

Even then you are not going to be able to sync the cameras accurately using directshow, the timing will be up to a frame interval (1/10s?) out.

Answer (score 1):

The typical problem is that USB bandwidth is insufficient for two cameras running in the same time, both cameras do fine independently but once you try them both - you have a failure. Another less frequent reason is the camera driver. Perhaps you can try it out in low resolution mode - if this attempt succeeds then version with insufficient bandwidth is the most likely one.

Sometimes you can work things around by connecting cameras to different USB hosts/controllers (not the ports on the same host!). The API itself does not limit you to use one camera at a time only.

Comment: I have definitely seen Microsoft Lifecam cameras claim all available bandwidth on a USB hub. You might need to add an extra USB controller card to your computer to succeed.

Comment: Is there any way to actually sense the the bandwidth was exceeded on Windows? MacOS AVFoundation notifies you with a specific error if this happens. It would be cool if there was a similar functionality on Windows, but I can't find anything.

Comment: @MarkConiglio it would be helpful but I am unaware of such notification on Windows